# Playwright doesnot return anything?

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, scrapy, playwright-python

```
 import scrapy
from scrapy_playwright.page import PageMethod

class PositionsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "positions"
    allowed_domains = ["https://trafigura.com/"]
    start_urls = ["https://careers.trafigura.com/TrafiguraCareerSite/search?"]


    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(
            self.start_urls[0],
            meta=dict(
                playwright = True,
                playwright_page_methods = [
                    PageMethod("wait_for_selector", 'section#results div[role="list"]')
                ]

            )
        )

    async def parse(self, response):
        for job in response.css('section#results div[role=list] div[role="listitem]'):
            yield{
                'title': job.css('a::text').get()
            }
```

[Error and Traceback](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ZUDuQ_Fx3-z-6gOZzmC3bpK3QceMCxxEV4gbrTk2uts/edit?usp=sharing)

I want to get multiple page from a JavaScript website. If i don't use playwright the code works fine.

Comment: Please copy and paste the full error and traceback you are receiving

Comment: I have uploaded full error and traceback with the link. Please any help is appreciated i am a beginner and stuck here.

Comment: your using a windows PC... Scrapy-playwright doesn't work on windows

Comment: Thank you. I used ubuntu on my VM and now it's working and i thought the latest version of playwright supported windows my mistake.